# z-index changes text color

Tags: html, css, wordpress, z-index

Hello I have found a strange issue on a website I am working on.

I can't figure out why this is happening, but some text with a color assigned via css looks darker then it should be. I am am using the [gantry framework](http://gantry-framework.org) for wordpress, but I cannot find any kind of css filter applied that would be causing this and there is no layers on top of the text.

What is weird is if I add position:relative and z-index:1 to the text's container it becomes lighter(closer to the correct color). I made a video of me toggling the z-index on and off with the chrome inspector. Can see it here; http://screencast.com/t/RsuK0h4C7o. I have set a block above the text to the same color so you can see the different text colors changing.

Another weird thing I noticed is that the text stops doing this at larger font sizes.

Comment: Can you post a url or a codepen/jsfiddle of what you're describing? it's easier to examine the code that way.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate it anywhere else.

Comment: Forgot to mention this happens in safari, chrome, and firefox, but not any of the IEs.

Comment: Post a URL of the code so we can have a look.